# How to tell when in the VBA window

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm working in C#.net and basically I want my plug-in to be able to tell if when the user saves, the save is coming from Excel itself or if the save is coming from the "Visual Basic for Application" window.

Is there a way to tell if the user is currently in the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Application" or not?

Edit:
I don't know if this is a full prof solution but I've found that .Application.ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet == null seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, this is quite straightforward. What specifically is the difficulty you are encountering?

Comment: Did ActiveSheet solve your problem?

Comment: Andre Neves - yes it did. Sorry for hte late reply

Answer (score 2):

on error resume next
set wbk = workbooks("MyBook.xls")
on error goto 0
is wbk is nothing then _
set wbk = workbooks.open("Mybook.xls")

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to return a boolean `True/False` if the project's VBE window is open. I'm not sure what the C# equivalent would be, but you may be able to simply check whether the Workbook's VBProject VB Editor is active:

```
Function IsVBEActive(wb as Workbook) As Boolean

Dim vbProj

Set vbProj = wb.vbProject

IsVBEActive <> vbProj.VBE.ActiveWindow Is Nothing

End Sub
```

**NOTE** This requires enabling trusted access to the VB Project Object Model:

[image]